# Five friends in a marathon race

Tags: logical-deduction

Five friends (A, B, C, D and E) run in a marathon race. At the start of the race: A is first, B is second, C is third, D is fourth and E is fifth. During the race the following events happened:

- A overtook a friend 5 times
- B overtook a friend 1 time
- C overtook a friend 0 times
- D overtook a friend 2 times
- E overtook a friend 4 times

Note a person can overtake another person multiple times. In what order did the five friends finish the race?

Comment: Does the statement "D overtook 2 of his friends" (for e.g.) imply that they overtook two different individuals or does it mean the same individual twice?

Comment: he can overtake same twice or two different. Let me rephrase the puzzle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The final result will be

> A first, B second, D third, E fourth, and C last

The reasoning is as follows:

> A must overtake on five occasions, but as she begins at the front she must also be overtaken five times. B, D, and E have a total of seven overtakings, so five of these must be overtaking A (otherwise A wouldn't be overtaken enough). But B can only overtake once, so at least four of the overtakings of A must be by D and E. Both D and E must overtake C before they overtake A (as C is never ahead of A), so D and E would each 'use up' one overtaking in getting past C. That means that D has only one possible chances of overtaking A, and E has only three (after they have overtaken C of course). So all of D and E's overtakings (once past C) are needed to allow them to overtake A a combined total of 4 times.   Of course that means that B, D, and E never overtake each other.

The 'timetable' of the race is:

> (B overtakes A | D overtakes C) (E overtakes C) (D overtakes A) (E overtakes A) (A overtakes E) (E overtakes A) (A overtakes E) (E overtakes A) (A overtakes E) (A overtakes D) (A overtakes B)

Or diagramatically (with time increasing horizontally from left to right):

> [image]

Comment: Great answer! Well done.

Comment: Timetable is missing *(D overtakes A)*

Comment: I am curious about the algorithm.  if they race had 10 friends, would you have been able to solve it in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: @TonyEnnis Even with 5 friends a puzzle of this form would usually have lots of different solution. This one is especially constructed to have only one. One can see that A starts in the front but has almost as many overtaking as everyone else combined and then start figuring out the details from there.

Comment: note that would be other possible answers if the race was run in multiple laps - *and* lapping another competitor was considered to be 'overtaking'. Probably not usually the case in a classic marathon, but I am not certain that a marathon *cannot* not be run in a series of laps.

Answer (score 1):

> ANSWER: ABDEC
>  1. ABCDE (START)
>  2. ABDCE (D overtakes C, D-1 i.e. D overtakes 1 friend)
>  3. ABDEC (E-1)
>  4. BADEC (B-1)
>  5. BDAEC (D-2)
>  6. BDEAC (E-2)
>  7. BDAEC (A-1)
>  8. BDEAC (E-3)
>  9. BDAEC (A-2)
>  10. BDEAC (E-4)
>  11. BDAEC (A-3)
>  12. BADEC (A-4)
>  13. ABDEC (A-5) (FINISH)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

> Let the number of times they were overtaken be $n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4$ and $n_5$. Then: 
>  $6>n_1-4>0$ 
>  $6>n_2+1>0$ 
>  $6>n_3+3>0$ 
>  $6>n_4+2>0$ 
>  $6>n_5+1>0$ 
>  $10>n_1>4$ 
>  $5>n_2$ 
>  $3>n_3$ 
>  $4>n_4$ 
>  $5>n_5$ 
>  $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5 = 12$  
>  Let $o_{abyc}$ be the number of times the $a$th friend mentioned was overtaken by the $b$th friend mentioned:
> $6>o_{1by2}+o_{1by3}+o_{1by4}+o_{1by5}-o_{2by1}-o_{3by1}-o_{4by1}-o_{5by1} + 1>0$ 
>  $6>o_{2by1}+o_{2by3}+o_{2by4}+o_{2by5}-o_{1by2}-o_{3by2}-o_{4by2}-o_{5by2} + 2>0$
>  $6>o_{3by1}+o_{3by2}+o_{3by4}+o_{3by5}-o_{1by3}-o_{2by3}-o_{4by3}-o_{5by3} + 3>0$
>  $6>o_{4by1}+o_{4by2}+o_{4by3}+o_{4by5}-o_{1by4}-o_{2by4}-o_{3by4}-o_{5by4} + 4>0$
>  $6>o_{5by1}+o_{5by2}+o_{5by3}+o_{5by4}-o_{1by5}-o_{2by5}-o_{3by5}-o_{4by5}+ 5>0$
>  $o_{2by1}+o_{3by1}+o_{4by1}+o_{5by1}=5$
>  $o_{1by2}+o_{3by2}+o_{4by2}+o_{5by2}=1$
>  $o_{1by3}+o_{2by3}+o_{4by3}+o_{5by3}=0$
>  $o_{1by4}+o_{2by4}+o_{3by4}+o_{5by4}=2$
>  $o_{1by5}+o_{2by5}+o_{3by5}+o_{4by5}=4$
>  $o_{n+mbyn} = o_{nbyn+m}(-1)$ 
>  $6>o_{1by2}+o_{1by4}+o_{1by5}-[o_{1by2}-a+(-b)+o_{1by4}-c+o_{1by5}-d]+1>0$ 
>  $6>o_{1by2}-a+o_{2by4}+o_{2by5}-[o_{1by2}+(-e)+o_{2by4}-f+o_{2by5}-g]+2>0$
>  $6>(-b)+(-e)+(+i)+(+j)+3>0$
>  $6>o_{1by4}-c+o_{2by4}-f+o_{4by5}-[o_{1by4}+o_{2by4}+(+i)+o_{4by5}-h]+4>0$
>  $6>o_{1by5}-d+o_{2by5}-g+o_{4by5}-h-[o_{1by5}+o_{2by5}+(+j)+o_{4by5}]+5>0$ 
>  $6>a+c+d+1>0$ 
>  $6>f+g+2-a>0$ 
> $6>i+j+3>0$ 
> $6>h+4-c-f-i>0$ 
> $6>5-d-g-h-j>0$ 
> $(o_{1by2}-a)+(o_{1by4}-c)+(o_{1by5}-d)=5$
>  $o_{1by2}+(o_{2by4}-f)+(o_{2by5}-g)=1$
>  $o_{1by4}+o_{2by4}+(+i)+(o_{4by5}-h)=2$
>  $o_{1by5}+o_{2by5}+(+j)+o_{4by5}=4$
>  $o_{1by2}<2$ 
>  $o_{2by4}, o_{2by5}, o_{1by4}, o_{2by4}<3$ 
>  $o_{4by5}<4$ 
>  $o_{1by5}<5$ 
>  $3<o_{1by4}+o_{1by5}<8$    
> If C was never overtaken, D and E could only overtake each other, with both overtaking an equal amount of times or one overtaking one more time, which isn't the case. So, C must have been overtaken at least once ($n_3=1$ or $2$). 
>  Also, since $n_1$ is at least 5, A must have been overtaken by E at least twice. This means if C was never overtaken by E, the latter could never have overtaken A, which isn't the case. So, C must have been overtaken by E once but not more times, because C can never make up for lost ground. 
>  If C was never overtaken by D, then A or B must have never been overtaken by it either, but then A must have been overtaken by B once and E four times ($n_1=5$). C ends up as 4th and D finishes last ($n_3=1, n_4=3)$, making $n_2+n_5=3$. D can only overtake E twice, with E overtaking D thrice, but this leads to a contradiction. 
>  So, C must have been overtaken by both D and E, ending up as last ($n_3=2$). $n_1+n_2+n_4+n_5=10$, $4<n_1<9$, $n_4<3$. 
>  $(o_{1by2}-a)+(o_{1by4}-c)+(o_{1by5}-d)=5$
>  $o_{1by2}+(o_{2by4}-f)+(o_{2by5}-g)=1$
>  $o_{1by4}+o_{2by4}+(o_{4by5}-h)=1$
>  $o_{1by5}+o_{2by5}+o_{4by5}=3$ 
>  $o_{1by2}, o_{1by4}, o_{2by4}<2$ 
>  $o_{2by5},o_{4by5}<3$ 
>  $o_{1by5}>2$ 
>  $o_{2by5},o_{4by5}=0$
>  $o_{1by5}=3$ 
> $g,h=0$ 
>  $o_{1by4}+o_{2by4}=1$ 
>  $o_{1by2}+o_{2by4}-f=1$ 
>   $(o_{1by2}-a)+(o_{1by4}-c)-d=2$ 
>  $o_{1by2}=1 $ 
> $o_{2by4}=f$ 
>  $1-f-a-c-d=1 $ 
>  $f,a,c,d=0$  
>   $o_{1by4}=1 $ 
>   $o_{2by4}=0 $ 
>   $6>a+c+d+1=1>0$ 
>  $6>f+2-a=2>0$ 
> $6>3-c-f=3>0$ 
> $6>4-d=4>0$ 
>  The solution is ABDEC.